# React native error this2.state is not a function error when changing state in class component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

This is the error I keep getting:
TypeError: _this2.state is not a function. (In '_this2.state({
range: value
})', '_this2.state' is an instance of Object)

This is the code:

```
 <Slider 
        style={styles.slider}
        disabled
        value={this.state.percent}
        onValueChange={(value)=>this.state({range:value})}
```

and these are the states:

```
constructor() {
super();
this.state = {
  
  range: 0,
  play: 1,
  playB: false,
  songLoaded: false,
  sound: new Audio.Sound(),
  percent: 0,

};
```

}

Comment: `setState` buddy

Comment: thank you so much I didnt notice the comment, chatgpt gave me the same answer xD

Answer (score 0):

This was solved by using:

```
setState
```

thanks DedaDev